# How to convert surnames beginning with O xxx to O'Xxx and those beginning with Mc xxx to McXxx

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this change should have been made before the data was entered into my database however could you tell me if there is a way to convert the names in my surnames column beginning with O xxx to O'Xxx and those beginning with 
Mc xxx to McXxx.

Thanks a million in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a quick solution like this:

```
UPDATE surnames
SET
  surname = CASE WHEN surname LIKE 'O %'
                 THEN CONCAT('O\'', SUBSTRING_INDEX(surname, 'O ', -1))
                 WHEN surname LIKE 'Mc %'
                 THEN CONCAT('Mc', SUBSTRING_INDEX(surname, 'Mc ', -1))
            END
WHERE
  surname LIKE 'O %' OR surname LIKE 'Mc %'
```

See fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d11e9/1).